Das wird dem Thema nicht gerecht
I have read the following in the subtitles at 11:31 of https://www.tagesschau.de/multimedia/sendung/tagesschau_20_uhr/video-1391804.html :

Sie haben das ohnehin zu klein geratene Sicherheitspaket zu einem Minipäckchen zusammengeschrumpft. Das wird dem Thema nicht geregt.

If I understood correctly, the spoken text has few extra words that are not relevant to my question.
Translation of the last sentence by DeepL translator:

This does not address the issue.

Is the last German sentence equivalent to

Das Thema wird dadurch nicht geregelt.

?
Does this last sentence have a subject? What are the grammatical roles of "das" and "dem Thema" in this sentence? I'm used to the fixed word order (subject + verb + complements) in English, and therefore struggle with some German sentences.

...zu '''einem''' Minipackchen ...

The subtitles say „Das wird dem Thema nicht gerecht.“ (gerecht, not geregt).
You can look here: https://www.dwds.de/wb/gerecht (Defintion 2), to see that „gerecht“ is used with werden and uses Dativ. „Das“ (demonstrative pronoun) refers to the previous sentence.
To break the sentence down more:
Das (pronoun for last sentence/subject)
wird (Verb conjugated to „das“)
dem Thema (Dativ because of the construction „etwas (Dativ) gerecht werden)
nicht (negation)
gerecht (Part of the same structure „gerecht werden“)

Given "gerecht" is an adjective instead of a verb, my understanding this sentence is not in passive voice. So is the literal translation of it "this becomes not fair to the issue" or "this will not be fair to the issue?

No. Treat it as a fixed expression. Einer Sache nicht gerecht werden. follows exactly the pattern of the more regular expression Einer Sache nicht gewachsen sein. This choice of the werden auxiliary as well as the fact that gerecht has no verb it could be a Partizip II of are both oddities.

@AlanEvangelista: "This will not be fair to the issue." is close, but it may be hard to understand what it actually means. "Fair" concerning what aspect? Put somewhat differently, it becomes clearer: "This does not give the issue the importance it deserves/requires."

There is a mistake, either in the subtitles or in your reading of it. It must read

Das wird dem Thema nicht gerecht.

Einer Sache gerecht werden is a fixed expression. It means "to be appropriate to a situation", or "to acknowledge something". The negation can be translated as "to fall short of something". In the video, the speaker wants to express that the measure proposed by the government coalition "fails to address the issue".
The term gerecht has a broad meaning in German. It can mean things such as

"just" as in eine ungerechte Schiedsrichterentscheidung - an "unjust decision of the umpire"
"fair" as in gerechte Löhne - "fair salaries"
"appropriate"
"according (to some standard)", as in artgerechte Tierhaltung -"animal breeding according to animal welfare" (literally it translates to "species-appropriate breeding")
"decent", in both the literal and the figurative meaning, as in ein gerechter Hunger - "a decent hunger"
"righteous"

The notions that are reflected in the English translations are often overlapping: If a hard working employee does not receive a decent salary, the salary might be described as both unjust and not appropriate with regards to their performance. That is why the translation of gerecht into English can sometimes be tricky and depends on context and intention.

Some grammatical observations.

Das wird dem Thema nicht gerecht.

To see that this is not passive, it is sufficient to recognise that gerecht is not derived from a verb (similar to gewohnt "wont", gelaunt "-humoured"). Note that even if such an adjective has a potential verbal base, it is in principle independent and can have a different meaning: gespannt (to tense, stretch, tighten vs. excited), gefasst (to grab, grip, grasp vs. calm, collected).
The copula werden is just a quirk here. The meaning of do justice to something is present also when gerecht is used attributively.

Für die dem Anlaß gerechte Musik sorgen die Zwickauer Kohlmeisen und die Silberberg-Musikanten aus Dresden. (Berliner Zeitung, 16.12.1995)

However, since the past participle of the copula is geworden (and not worden like that of the passive auxiliary), examples in perfect tense can also help to show that the sentence is active:

Der FC Porto ist seiner Favoritenrolle gerecht geworden und hat sich nach 1987 zum zweiten Mal in der Vereins-Geschichte den Fußball-Weltpokal gesichert. (Berliner Zeitung, 13.12.2004)

To see that das has the role of subject, one can look for examples with a plural.

Doch all diese Etiketten werden dem Aufstand nicht gerecht. (Der Tagesspiegel, 05.05.2003)

Or, with the subject in the singular and a dative plural:

So ein Schlagwort wird den Problemen nicht gerecht. (Berliner Zeitung, 31.05.2002)

In these examples, the datives dem Thema, Anlass, Aufstand; der Rolle; den Problemen belong to gerecht. In German, adjectives can govern case just like verbs.

den Ärger leid (acc.)
dem Wahnsinn nah (dat.)
des Wartens überdrüssig (gen.)

